# How to create opaque background like in the bottom panel in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, background-color

I want to create label with the background color like in the bottom panel of iOS7-8, something like this:

[image: Like this]

Or create a view and inside of it put label. How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use blureffect

For example

```
    let blurEffect =  UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
    let bluredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    bluredEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)
    self.imageview.addSubview(bluredEffectView)
```

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: thanks! How can I make an  opacity about 0.8? Can I do it?

Comment: You can not set alpha when using `UIVisualEffectView`. You can set the style of `UIBlurEffect `,there are 3 of them:light,extraLight,dark